# How to store value in an array of a struct in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct, segmentation-fault

I have a struct like this:

```
struct student {
    
    char name[50];
    int grade;
};
```

I want to create an array of structs(one for every student,using malloc).

```
 struct student *studs=malloc(STUDENT_NUM*sizeof(struct student));
```

After that i looped over my arrays containing student info and then tried to store those infos in each struct.So far I am getting Segmentation fault but I dont understand why.

```
for(int i=0;i<STUDENT_NUM;i++){
        strcpy(Names[i],studs[i].name);
        studs[i].grade=Grades[i];
}
```

I have found another approach,that is working,but I just want to find out how could I make it work using the struct above.

So the "solution I found is actually,changing the struct field to:

```
char *name;
```

And then in the loop I just allocate space for that array like this:

```
studs[i].name=malloc(50*sizeof(char));
```

Why does my first approach give me Segmentation fault.Havent I allocated memory by using that initialization  `char name[50];`?
**Also to note that,I am just learning C(if it wasnt obvious).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `Names`? Please provide complete code as a [mre]. But for starters, note that the first param to `strcpy` is the destination and the second is the source. So `strcpy(Names[i],studs[i].name);` looks like it has the parameters in the wrong order if you are trying to copy into the struct. So that is likely the cause of the crash as it is trying to copy from `studs[i].name` which is not a valid string. Try swapping the params: `strcpy(studs[i].name, Names[i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just ran my code as [kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003365/kaylum) commented. The mistake was not where I was looking for.It was just my fault for overlooking the strcpy() funtion and giving the arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).